# Inclue Web Page in livecode

Tags: livecode

I am new to LiveCode, and I would like to embed a web page in a map. Realize the user then on a button, which opens a map, this map and provided with a back button, and I would like to display a site directly in LiveCode. How can I do, so that we see on the whole map (or almost) the site? do you need a particular widget?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completely, but there is a web browser widget that you can drag onto the card. It is in the Tools palette and looks like a world globe. You drag it onto the card then set its URL property:

```
set the URL of widget "myBrowser" to "https://livecode.com"
```

Comment: Ok, thank you I try that and report my expérience

Comment: Ok, I try it and it's Great !

Comment: Good to hear, Freddy. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as such.